# Para que serve o . em <form action="." method="post">?

Tags: html, django, formulário

Estou iniciando no Django e fazendo umas alterações em código já escrito por alguém. Percebi que no *form* em vez da usual `"/action page"` para onde os dados serão submetidos, como [neste](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_form.asp) exemplo do W3Schools:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

o atributo `action` possui um ponto, por quê?

```
<form action="." method="post">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso está relacionado só ao HTML. O cliente tem que enviar os dados do formulário para alguma página, e ali no `action` você diz qual, até aí você já sabe. Se você quer enviar para a própria página onde está o formulário você faria como? Pode colocar o endereço completo da página. Ou pode simplesmente colocar um ponto que é a mesma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).