# Como abrir uma nova janela através do PHP com os resultados de um SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um formulário em que nele o usuário poderá selecionar diversas matérias, sendo então selecionada uma matéria, através do PHP eu irei puxar do banco de dados por `SELECT` e irei mostrar na tela com `echo` os resultados.

**Meu código :**

```
<form id = "questions_form" method= "post">
   <select class= "box-select" name="select1">
      <option value="value1">Estrutura de Banco de Dados</option>                         
   </select>
   <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Resultado"/>
   <div class = "resultados-lista">
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nome_conteudo = 'Estrutura de Banco de Dados' ";

      $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
         $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
         switch ($select1) {
            case 'value1':
               echo  "<li>" . $fetch[0] . "</li>";
            break;

            default:
            # código
            break;
         }
      }
      ?>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Mas por muitas das matérias terem mais de 30 perguntas, fica muito ruim e inviável elas serem mostradas na mesma página. Por conta disto, eu gostaria de dar um `target` em uma nova página para somente mostrar estas perguntas. Mas não sei como eu posso fazer isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é:

```
<form id = "questions_form" method= "post" action="resultado.php">
   <select class= "box-select" name="select1">
      <option value="value1">Estrutura de Banco de Dados</option>                         
   </select>
   <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Resultado"/>
</form>
```

E criar um arquivo resultado.php com o resultado.

```
      <?php

      $query = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nome_conteudo = 'Estrutura de Banco de Dados' ";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
         $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
         switch ($select1) {
            case 'value1':
               echo  "<li>" . $fetch[0] . "</li>";
            break;

            default:
            # código
            break;
         }
      }
      ?>
```

Isso certamente irá funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar mais um atributo no form, o action, quando o formulário for submetido, vai ser direcionado para essa outra página. Nessa outra pagina que será feita a consulta ao banco e exibido o resultado.

Mais explicações [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184732/para-que-serve-o-em-form-action-method-post), [aqui](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/tutorial.forms.php) e na [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)